# How to show admob interstitial ad after splashscreen using the new SplashScreen compat library

Tags: android, admob, splash-screen

How to show admob interstitial ad after splashscreen using the new SplashScreen compat library

the only thing that we do is call `installSplashScreen()` in mainactivity i.e the activity which is shown right after the spalshscreen

how do we manage to show an interstitial after the splashscreen

Comment: loading interstital ad at load is disallowed implementation https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en . You might want to take a look at "App Open Ads"

Comment: it is not an ad  `at load` but after the splash screen is shown , it was allowed earlier and even now few apps have it, the question is about after the mandatory migration to `SplashScreen compat library` in `android 12`  how can we implement the same feature.